# An issue with angular 4 select element behavior on selecting an option

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an angular 4 (v4.2.5 cli) app and I have encountered the following issue:

I am using a select element in the following manner:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <select class="col-xs-12" [(ngModel)]="roleId" (ngModelChange)="changeSelected($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let type of userTypes" [ngValue]="type" [selected]="type.Name === role">{{ type.Name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Essentialy I wanted to bind the selection event to a specific action in my component class:

```
changeSelected(event) {
    this.roleId = event.ID;
}
```

And it works, when I select one of the options the event is fired and the field "roleId" gets set. However, the selected item just disappears from view (I remain with an empty option). I am testing my solution in chrome. Is [ngValue] attribute binding interferes in some way with the [selected] attribute binding? Am I missing something? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you need not use `selected` when using `ngModel`

Comment: You *either* use `[(ngModel)]="..."` or `[ngModel]="..." (ngModelChange)="..."`, don't mix the two.

Comment: Yes, but the data of the *ngFor loop comes from the server, and when I want to edit a specific user I want an appropriate option field to be displayed whenever the user edit modal box opens (the select element is contained there and input fields get prepopulated by the data coming from a server by [(ngModel)] binding. So how can I achieve this while still being subscribed to changeSelected event ?

Comment: jonrsharpe thanks a lot, that was it. Of course, [(ngModel)] is a dual way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change the value of a select, you don't need to trigger an event for that. Just delete your `ngModelChange` attribute, your `roleId` property will have the value you selected in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You either use `[(ngModel)]="..."` or `[ngModel]="..."` `(ngModelChange)="..."`, don't mix the two. Thanks jonrsharpe, once again.